# Gcd is a Regular Language

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, automata

Show that GCD = {z|z = gcd(x,y), where x, y are binary numbers} is a regular
language. [Hint: There is an algorithm that deals with 0s and 1s for this problem.]

Comment: To clarify, the language is triples such that the first element is the gcd of the other two?

Comment: yes "Gcd" of x,y

Comment: What is the alphabet you are considering?

Comment: the question doesn't specify I think can be anything.

Comment: Any thoughts? @J.-E.Pin

Comment: @Jared I am sorry, but I don't understand your question. I will ask to close your question as unclear.

Comment: it's clear but missing alphabet which you need to figure out them that's it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The language $L =\{(a,b,c) |\, a = \gcd(b,c)\}$ where strings are binary representations is **not** regular.

Let $p$ be the pumping constant of the pumping lemma. Choose a string $(a_0, b_0, c_0) \in L$ such that $|a_o| \ge p$. Then it can be decomposed $a_0 = a_x a_y a_z$ where $|a_x a_y| \le p$ and $|a_y| \ge 1$ and  $\forall n, (a_x a_y^n a_z , b_0, c_0) \in L$.

But for $n$ large enough, the front part of the triple can no longer be the gcd since it grows even bigger than $b_0$ and $c_0$.

Comment: but gcd is regular language

Comment: Then I think you need to make precise exactly which strings are in the language. In the formulation I considered, it isn't regular.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm this not help to prove it regular ?

Comment: I'm not sure at this point what language you want. There really is no such language called "gcd" so it must be formalized somehow

Comment: So, it is regular, the trivial interpretation. The answer is the whole set of binary numbers since gcd is closed over the natural numbers.

Comment: is that can help?

Comment: what you think?

Comment: Sorry, I tried but I couldn't think of an interpretation of the question that makes gcd a regular language.

Comment: Thanks I really appropriated.